# Simple way to "Update Project" with IntelliJ IDEA & Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

I have a Mercurial repo on a central server (`mercurial-server` package on Ubuntu; repo URLs are of the form `ssh://host/repo`), and a local working copy. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 and its Mercurial plugin (hg4idea).

I'm trying to do something simple: a colleague has checked in changes (commit & push to server), and I want to get those. In other words, I want to update the project (in Subversion lingo?).

IDEA's **Update Project** (Ctrl-T / Cmd-T) only produces this message:

> Error: Skipped
>   "/path/to/working-copy". No default
>   update path.

Here's the simplest (and only) way I found so far: choose Mercurial -> **Pull Changesets...** which brings up this dialog:

[image]

...where you copy-paste the repo URL (something like `ssh://host/project`).

Next choose Mercurial -> **Update to...**

[image]

...and click OK.

Is there a quicker way to do this? By somehow defining the "default update path" perhaps?

I wouldn't want to always fall back to command-line (`hg pull && hg update`) for such simple operation, but it seems like I have to if it really is so clumsy in IDEA.

(I'm new to Mercurial, so forgive me if I'm doing everything wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the specifics of how IntelliJ's plugin works, I can offer this, from [hgrc(5)](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths), the `paths` section:

> default
>
> Directory or URL to use when
>   pulling if no source is specified.
>   Default is set to repository from
>   which the current repository was
>   cloned.

So it seems that your repo local hgrc file doesn't contain the usual `default` path for the clone source.

You might want to try to add it manually and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed fixed the "No default update path" problem (+1). But now I get 'Pulled in 0 remote heads in repository [...], not merging.  Multiple heads in this branch in repository [...] before the update (use "hg heads ." and "hg merge" to merge)'. I don't know how to do those things in IDEA UI, *and* I probably don't understand enough of Mercurial yet to fully understand what that means... :/

Comment: @Jonik: I don't recognize the whole message so that looks like a mix of an IntelliJ message with a Mercurial one. A head is a changeset with no children. What it's telling is that the branch you're on has more than one head (probably the consequence of a `pull`), and you should merge.