# Pull/Merging in IntelliJ Idea: "Error: Skipped... No default update path."

Tags: intellij-idea, merge, mercurial, bitbucket, pull

I'm a junior so this question may be foolish. I refactored a program in IntelliJ and now I'm trying to push it up to the main repo on BitBucket. I'm using Mercurial for VCS. I was able to commit the changes to the local repo without issue, but when I try to Pull/Merge, I get the following message:

```
Error: Skipped "C:/Users/me/ProgramFolder." No default update path.
```

There are very few Google results on this error's phrasing, so perhaps I'm using the wrong terms. I don't understand this error; I think it means Mercurial doesn't know where to put the pulled code, but I'm not sure, and even if that were the case I do not understand why. The project folder has never moved, and Mercurial's settings have never changed.

What is happening here? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Look in `c:/users/me/programfolder/.hg/hgrc`. There should be a line like: `default = https://bitbucket.org/your-project` Is there such a line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to "Update Project" with IntelliJ IDEA & Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401971/simple-way-to-update-project-with-intellij-idea-mercurial)

Comment: Interestingly the message "No default update path" seems specific to IntelliJ, that text doesn't originate from mercurial itself.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams Interestingly, there is no hgrc file in that folder. Perhaps this is a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Mercurial was looking for a configuration file (hgrc) and could not find it, so IntelliJ was throwing an error.

I manually created the hgrc and set the default path:

I navigated to

```
C:/Users/Me/ProgramFolder/.hg
```

and created a file called ProgramName.txt, then in that file I specified the repository:

```
[paths]
default = https://me@bitbucket.org/me/MyProgram
```

Then I saved the file and renamed it hgrc.hgrc to convert it to that file type.

When I ran the Pull/Merge action again, everything worked.